# java ScriptEngine failed on array methods

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I have problems executing an array of JavaScript methods in Java ScriptEngine.

I use JDK 8.

Example

```
@Test
public void arrayMethod() throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine engine;
    engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String script = "function f1() { return [\"string2\",\"string3\"].some(item => o1==item); }";
    engine.eval(script);
    engine.put("o1", "string1");
    Boolean result =  (Boolean) (((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("f1"));
    LOG.info(result.toString());
}
```

Result

java.lang.AssertionError: Failed generating bytecode for :1

```
at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase$BytecodeGenerationPhase.transform(CompilationPhase.java:431)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase.apply(CompilationPhase.java:624)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:655)
```

I try to use other methods (every, etc.) with the same result. There are no syntax errors, but java script compiler could not create code. 
My version of ScriptEngine does not have method includes for arrays. It return syntax error.
How is it possible to work with arrays in ScriptEngine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an arrow function, which was introduced with ES6. JDK8 Nashorn does not support ES6, but only ES5.1. Convert your arrow function into a standard function and it will run:

```
String script = "function f1() { return [\"string2\",\"string3\"].some(function(item){return o1==item;})}";
```

Comment: Thanks it helps 
function f1() { return ["s2","s3"].some( function(item) { return o1==item; } ); }

Answer (score 1):

> I use JDK 8.

For your script you need at least JDK 9, since there is an arrow function, which is supported starting from Java 9 only.

See: [JEP 292: Implement Selected ECMAScript 6 Features in Nashorn](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/292)